# What does the phpMyAdmin icon (box of books?) beside certain databases mean?

Tags: phpmyadmin

The image below is an example of the icon I am referring to. It is only present on 4 out of 50 databases.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That indicates that two or more databases are being grouped together based on a common prefix.

By default, databases with a prefix and underscore are grouped together; so `test_keys`, `test_tables`, and `test_unicode` would all be grouped together under `test`, to get to each database you'd click the plus sign to expand them.

The separator can be configured with [`$cfg['NavigationTreeDbSeparator']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeDbSeparator). There's similar grouping behavior available at the table level with the configuration directive [`$cfg['NavigationTreeTableSeparator']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeTableSeparator), and the whole thing can be disabled by setting [`$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping'] = 'false';`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeEnableGrouping)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this great and helpful information!