# MySQL. Partially clone of database

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I'm using VCL C++ app for connect to MySQL server:

```
mysql_real_connect(mysql,"localhost","user","pass","",0,NULL,0);
DBRequest("USE `kouzi`");
DBRequest("SET NAMES cp1251");
... do something
```

Then I need to create instance of original DB with same structure, but without some data:

```
DBRequest("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `kouzi_new` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci");
DBRequest("CREATE TABLE kouzi_new.table1 LIKE kouzi.table1");
DBRequest("INSERT kouzi_new.table1 SELECT * FROM kouzi.table1");
```

The problem is that new database `kouzi_new` created IN origin database `kouzi`. Not in the "root" level:
[new db inside origin db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Rmw.jpg)

Also I need to insert function inside new db:

```
DBRequest("CREATE FUNCTION ROUND_TO_EVEN(val DECIMAL(32,16), places INT) RETURNS DECIMAL(32,16) RETURN IF(ABS(val - TRUNCATE(val, places)) * POWER(10, places + 1) = 5 AND NOT CONVERT(TRUNCATE(ABS(val) * POWER(10, places), 0), UNSIGNED) % 2 = 1, TRUNCATE(val, places), ROUND(val, places))");
```

And it throws error:

```
[1304] FUNCTION ROUND_TO_EVEN already exists
```

The question is how I can create database at the "root" level as other db's, not inside this? Inside app, of course. :)
Thanks.

Comment: i can't reproduce your problem, which Version of mysqöl are you using. The actual 8.0.22 creates a new folder in the data directory

Comment: MySQL does not support databases inside databases. What you see is a feature of phpmyadmin to group databases (not inside MySQL, just in that list), see [What does the phpMyAdmin icon (box of books?) beside certain databases mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956560)

Comment: Erm... I'm using MySQL 5.7.17 (AppServ 8.6.0). Maybe the this is the cause.

Comment: If this is the feature of phpMyAdmin then I have no idea why it didn't allow to create function because of "function already exists".

Comment: Your statements to create a new table included the name of the new (and old) database explicitly, e.g. "CREATE TABLE **kouzi_new.** table1 LIKE **kouzi.** table1". Your create function-statement didn't, so it is using the current database (the one you specified with `use kouzi` in line 2, and there it already exists). Just fix either of those (use `use`, or add a database prefix).

Comment: Thanks for help. Fixed via adding "USE newDB" just after "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS..."